# Set Textures DX12

Tags: c++, directx12

```
    for (int j = 0; j < MeshNums; j++)
    {
        CD3DX12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE hDescriptor = CD3DX12_CPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE(m_SrvDescriptorHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart());
        hDescriptor.Offset(j, m_CbvSrvUavDescriptorSize);

        m_CommandList->SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable(0, hDescriptor);

        m_CommandList->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &m_Scene[j]->VertexBufferView());

        m_CommandList->DrawInstanced(
            m_Scene[j]->DrawArgs.VertexCount, 1, 0, 0);
    }
```

C++ DX12 project. I'm trying to draw several meshes in a row on the screen, and apply a texture to each subsequent mesh. But I get a compilation error on the line:

```
m_CommandList->SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable(0, hDescriptor);
```

How to solve a problem?

Comment: What is the full text of your compiler error?

Comment: I found, m_SrvDescriptorHeap->GetCPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart() should be m_SrvDescriptorHeap->GetGPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart() i.e. CPU -> GPU change.

Comment: If you've solved your problem, feel free to post your solution as an answer below. Or if you still beed help, edit your question to show the error or issue you're still facing.

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int j = 0; j < MeshNums; j++)
    {
        CD3DX12_GPU_DESCRIPTOR_HANDLE hDescriptor(m_SrvDescriptorHeap->GetGPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart());
        hDescriptor.Offset(j, m_CbvSrvUavDescriptorSize);

        m_CommandList->SetGraphicsRootDescriptorTable(0, hDescriptor);

        m_CommandList->IASetVertexBuffers(0, 1, &m_Scene[j]->VertexBufferView());

        m_CommandList->DrawInstanced(
            m_Scene[j]->DrawArgs.VertexCount, 1, 0, 0);
    }
```

There was a syntax error in the code. Necessary:

GetGPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart()

Was:

GetСPUDescriptorHandleForHeapStart()